# Unable to close Garage door with remote

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener, troubleshooting, garage-door

[I’ve made a video of the issue.](https://goo.gl/photos/ScFYgTckDkPdsQka9)
I have a craftsman garage door mechanism and can open the garage door with the remote but unable to close my garage door via the remote. I can do both the tasks via the wall button.
I got the house recently and the garage has been closed for six years. Is there something wrong I am doing here?
Can someone help please…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this. If you check out the video, you’ll see the green track sensor blinking and that meant it was no in alignment with the other eye. Minor adjustments to the fixture and the light went solid green and the remote was back on track!

Answer (score 2):

If you watch the back of the opener starting at around :54 in the video, you'll notice that the LED indicator flashes 4 times.  For Craftsman openers, this is almost always the code for an issue with the interrupt sensors.  Make sure that they are clean and getting power (no wire breaks, etc.), and then follow the instructions in the owners manual for aligning them.  If you don't have a copy of the manual, get the model number off of the opener and check to see if they have a .pdf at the manufacturer's website ([www.searspartsdirect.com](http://www.searspartsdirect.com)).

Comment: I agree.  Flickering green light on the IR sensors indicates alignment problem or sensor  issue.  From the Sears website on this: "When a safety sensor fails, the remote won't work and the lights on the motor unit blink when you press the remote. To test the sensor, connect the photo eyes directly to the motor unit with short wires. Hold the eyes close together, facing each other."

Comment: @chris, was the root cause. I wrote the explanation as another answer. Hope that’s fine.